# Azure Blob storage SDK: Switch off logging

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an application which is using azure.storage.blob python module.

Evidently, when I am executing it, the module is dumping its log data in the logger which I dont want because it is large and my own application info gets lost in between it.

Is there any way to remove the logger from azure.storage.blob python module?

log sample:

> INFO:azure.storage.common.storageclient:Client-Request-ID=d5afebc0-aa84-11e8-be16-000d3ae070ae
>   Outgoing request: Method=PUT,
>   Path=/marketingcloud-raw-events/2018/8/27/bounce.csv,
>   Query={'timeout': None}, Headers={'Content-Length': '38176',
>   'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28',
>   'x-ms-lease-id': None, 'x-ms-client-request-id':
>   'd5afebc0-aa84-11e8-be16-000d3ae070ae', 'If-Match': None,
>   'If-Modified-Since': None, 'If-None-Match': None, 'User-Agent':
>   'Azure-Storage/1.3.0-1.3.1 (Python CPython 2.7.15; Linux
>   4.15.0-1021-azure)'

Comment: Can you share some sample logging ? also some code ? Which method are you using ?

Comment: I am getting something like these: 
INFO:azure.storage.common.storageclient:Client-Request-ID=d5afebc0-aa84-11e8-be16-000d3ae070ae Outgoing request: Method=PUT, Path=/marketingcloud-raw-events/2018/8/27/bounce.csv, Query={'timeout': None}, Headers={'Content-Length': '38176', 'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 'x-ms-lease-id': None, 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd5afebc0-aa84-11e8-be16-000d3ae070ae', 'If-Match': None, 'If-Modified-Since': None, 'If-None-Match': None, 'User-Agent': 'Azure-Storage/1.3.0-1.3.1 (Python CPython 2.7.15; Linux 4.15.0-1021-azure)',

Comment: if you look at this file (from github repo) https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-common/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py, it seems you cant disable the logger. You can create a new issue to get this change done

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned in the comment, you could find the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-common/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py) of log data is encapsulated in the `azure.storage.blob` python sdk. As I know, there's no such switch to close this logging mechanism.

1.You can encapsulate the SDK by yourself and get rid of these redundant logs.

2.Or you just could try to add special tags to the application logs and filter out redundant other log data.

3.You could commit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure to make the the log data as optional.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: For now I have chose the 2nd option since I did not have time to venture into the code of blob library but would love to do it sometime later.

Answer (score 31):

This is actually very easy to do.  You can adjust any logger.

Just do this near the start of your program to switch verbosity from INFO to WARNING, or whatever you prefer.

```
logging.getLogger("azure.storage.common.storageclient").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP (and me) is looking for!

Comment: This helped me too.

Comment: This reminds me to set level for whatever azure.storage module. Thanks!

Comment: Please also read the documentation at <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-logging> already mentioned by @chris below.  This provides a general solution for all resources.

Comment: Adding additional info for others who might land here looking for a general solution to set logging level only for azure libraries: I additionally noticed that logs related to Authentication are not suppressed even with logging.getLogger('azure').setLevel(logging.WARNING). The logs are coming from 'msal' and require logging.getLogger("msal").setLevel(logging.WARNING). This is not mentioned in the Azure documentation link above.

Answer (score 8):

Some messages are related to http calls. Also try the following:

```
logger=logging.getLogger('azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue that the azure blob API was spamming my log stream.
When you build a `BlobClient` you can also pass a custom logger which you can control as you like.

```
logger = logging.getLogger("logger_name")
logger.disabled = True
my_blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string("azure blob connection string", container_name="container", blob_name="blob", logger=logger)
```

Answer (score 2):

The heavy INFO logging from the azure.storage.blob library was filling my logs with REDACTED junk when doing basic requests.

```
2022-04-19 13:46:15,760 [Thread-3 (worker)] [INFO]  Request URL: 'https://storage-url/folder/blob'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
'x-ms-range': 'REDACTED'
'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
'Accept': 'application/xml'
'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.11.0 Python/3.10.4 (Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0)'
'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
'x-ms-client-request-id': '43a4b6e8-bf93-11ec-a3c9-00224893b074'
'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
```

Using @MRTN's answer I found that managing the logger where you generate the client and adding it to the logging parameter stopped the spam.

```
import logging 
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

logger = logging.getLogger('azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

class AzureBlobDownloader:
    def __init__(self, account_url, access_key):
        self.blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient(
            account_url=account_url, 
            credential=access_key,
            logging=logger
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-logging

where it shows how you can also use more general namespaces. For example:

```
import logging

# Set the logging level for all azure-storage-* libraries
logger = logging.getLogger('azure.storage')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Set the logging level for all azure-* libraries
logger = logging.getLogger('azure')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```